# Can't change a node module mock created with genMockFromModule

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I do a module level mocking placing a module.js file inside the `__mocks__` folder aside of node_modules. (project root level)

- `node_modules/`
- `__mocks__/module.js`

Then in the module.js file inside `__mocks__` I do:

```js
const api = jest.genMockFromModule("module");

module.exports = api;
```

It works fine (the mocking is done), but when I try to change any mocked function implementation of "module" on my tests (module.someFunc) it doesn't replace the mocked implementation:

```js
import * as api from "module";
api.someFunc.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve([]);
// OR
api.someFunc = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve([]);
// OR
jest.onSpy(api, "someFunc").mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve([]);

// Tryied with commonJS to
const api = require("module")

api.someFunc.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve([]);
// OR
api.someFunc = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve([]);
// OR
jest.onSpy(api, "someFunc").mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve([]);
```

Using typescript with ts-jest;

Jest config:

```js
module.exports = {
    preset: "ts-jest/presets/js-with-babel",
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            diagnostics: false,
        }
    },
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/", "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/setup/"],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        "react-testing-library/cleanup-after-each",
        "jest-dom/extend-expect",
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "\\.(scss)$": "<rootDir>node_modules/jest-css-modules"
    }
};
```